# Create a universal custom control

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Hi I created one app that show you all your devices in your network. I would like to encapsulate all this code and controls in one "custom control" for use it in others apps.

I only find information about WPF custom controls, however when I tried to create a WPF custom control and then reference it to my Universal App, I got an error. I have searched about it and It seems that you can't use WPF controls in Universal Apps.

My idea is create something like "NetworkDevices", then I would put in my Universal App Main XAML:

```
<NetworkDevices Property1= ..  Event1=........ ></NetworkDevices>
```

and then I would have my custom control embebed in my Universal App.

[image: My idea]

Thanks for your time.

Update: 
[Visual Studio Solution and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC6Yr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `Templated Control` in a Universal Windows class library (so it can be reused in other apps).

[image: Templated control]

I suppose you know how to do the rest (as you've created WPF custom controls, but as a reference you can use [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/15/building-a-custom-control-using-xaml-and-c.aspx) as well to guid you through step by step.